# Incomplete Type When Compiling, type already defined

Tags: c, types, struct, compiler-errors, header-files

So I have my header file listed below. For some reason, when I attempt to compile I get the following errors.

```
orders.h:39: error: field ‘category_transactions’ has incomplete type
orders.h:51: error: field ‘address’ has incomplete type
orders.h:52: error: field ‘successful_trans’ has incomplete type
orders.h:53: error: field ‘failed_trans’ has incomplete type
```

I have looked over some other people's similar problems and the responses. I believe they should be defined due to my typedefs. What am I doing wrong?

NOTE: I am not trying to create a pointer to the items, I am trying to use shared memory and have been told to avoid pointers for that purpose. I was thinking about attempting to simply make them all arrays of length 1, but I'm not sure if that is just a round about way to solve the issue, or whether it will actually solve the issue.

Thank you.

```
#ifndef ORDERS_H
#define ORDERS_H 

 #define MAX_TRANS 30 
 #define MAX_CATEGORY 4
 #define MAX_CUSTOMERS 30  
 #define MAX_CUSTOMER_ID 30 
 #define MAX_CUSTOMER_NAME 50 
 #define MAX_ITEM_NAME 100 
 #define MAX_CATEGORY_NAME 30
 #define MAX_ZIP 10 
 #define MAX_STATE 20 
 #define MAX_STREET_CITY 80  
 #define SEM_ORDER_LIST "/order@@list" 
 #define SEM_USER_DATABASE "/user@@db" 
 #define SEM_PENDING_LIST "/pend@@list"

 typedef struct Transaction Transaction; 
 typedef struct Item Item; 
 typedef struct Customer Customer; 
 typedef struct Mailing_Address Mailing_Address; 
 typedef struct Category Category;
 typedef struct Category_List Category_List;  
 typedef struct Customer_List Customer_List; 
 typedef struct Transaction_List Transaction_List; 



 struct Category{ 
    char category_name[MAX_CATEGORY_NAME]; 
    Transaction_List category_transactions; 
 }; 

 struct Category_List{ 
    unsigned int curr_length; 
    Category all_categories[MAX_CATEGORY]; 
 }; 

 struct Customer{ 
    char customer_name[MAX_CUSTOMER_NAME]; 
    char customer_id[MAX_CUSTOMER_ID];
    double  credit_balance; 
    Mailing_Address address; 
    Transaction_List successful_trans;
    Transaction_List failed_trans;  
 }; 

 struct Customer_List{ 
    unsigned int curr_length;  
    Customer all_customers[MAX_CUSTOMERS];
 };  

 struct Item{ 
    char item_name[MAX_ITEM_NAME]; 
    double price; 
    char category_name[MAX_CATEGORY_NAME]; 
 }; 

 struct Mailing_Address{ 
    char zipcode[MAX_ZIP]; 
    char state[MAX_STATE]; 
    char street_city[MAX_STREET_CITY]; 
 }; 

 struct Transaction{ 
    Item  object; 
    char customer_id[MAX_CUSTOMER_ID];  
 }; 

 struct Transaction_List{ 
    unsigned int curr_length;  
    Transaction all_transactions[MAX_TRANS];  
 };     

#endif
```

Comment: You need a definition for `struct Transaction_List` (giving the sequence of its members), and very probably for each of your other `struct` ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you define the struct objects (like `struct myStruct member;`), compiler needs to know the definition of `myStruct` in order to allocate storage. You have only typedef's which is just an alias and doesn't tell about the actual structs.

If you re-order the struct defintions to make sure they are visible when others use, you should be fine.

```
 typedef struct Transaction Transaction; 
 typedef struct Item Item; 
 typedef struct Customer Customer; 
 typedef struct Mailing_Address Mailing_Address; 
 typedef struct Category Category;
 typedef struct Category_List Category_List;  
 typedef struct Customer_List Customer_List; 
 typedef struct Transaction_List Transaction_List; 

 struct Mailing_Address{
    char zipcode[MAX_ZIP];
    char state[MAX_STATE];
    char street_city[MAX_STREET_CITY];
 };

 struct Item{
    char item_name[MAX_ITEM_NAME];
    double price;
    char category_name[MAX_CATEGORY_NAME];
 };


 struct Transaction{
    Item  object;
    char customer_id[MAX_CUSTOMER_ID];
 };

 struct Transaction_List{
    unsigned int curr_length;
    Transaction all_transactions[MAX_TRANS];
 };


 struct Category{ 
    char category_name[MAX_CATEGORY_NAME]; 
    Transaction_List category_transactions; 
 }; 

 struct Category_List{ 
    unsigned int curr_length; 
    Category all_categories[MAX_CATEGORY]; 
 }; 

 struct Customer{ 
    char customer_name[MAX_CUSTOMER_NAME]; 
    char customer_id[MAX_CUSTOMER_ID];
    double  credit_balance; 
    Mailing_Address address; 
    Transaction_List successful_trans;
    Transaction_List failed_trans;  
 }; 

 struct Customer_List{ 
    unsigned int curr_length;  
    Customer all_customers[MAX_CUSTOMERS];
 };
```